# React Highchart: Synchronized chart and tooltip is not highlighting the points

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts

I am using `highchart-react-official`, I am using it draw two charts:

1) Line chart with multiple series

2) Column Chart.

Now I want, if I hover over a point in first chart, it should display highlight point on both lines of first chart and column chart in second chart. Like a synchronized chart: http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/51zdn0jz/6/

This is my code:

```
((H) => {
  H.Pointer.prototype.reset = () => undefined;

  /**
   * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and 
   draw crosshair
  */
  H.Point.prototype.highlight = function highlight(event) {
    event = this.series.chart.pointer.normalize(event);
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
  };

  H.syncExtremes = function syncExtremes(e) {
    const thisChart = this.chart;

    if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') {
      // Prevent feedback loop
      Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, (chart) => {
        if (chart && chart !== thisChart) {
          if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) {
            // It is null while updating
            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, {
              trigger: 'syncExtremes',
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
})(Highcharts);


componentDidMount() {
  this.changeChart();

  ['mousemove', 'touchmove', 'touchstart'].forEach((eventType) => {
    document
      .getElementById('tab__charts')
      .addEventListener(eventType, (e) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i += 1) {
          const chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
          // let secSeriesIndex = 1;
          if (chart) {
            // Find coordinates within the chart
            const event = chart.pointer.normalize(e);

            // Get the hovered point

            chart.series.forEach(series => {
              const point = series.searchPoint(event, true);
              if (point) {
                point.highlight(e);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Some imporant chart config:

```
tooltip: {
  enabled: true,
  useHTML: true,
  shared: true,
}

xAxis: {
  events: {
    setExtremes: (e) => {
      Highcharts.syncExtremes(e);
    },
  }
}
```

Now this code is working perfectly by synchronizing tooltip on both charts. But the issue is in first chart, it has two lines, when I hover over first line it hightlights the point with round circle, but the second line is not getting highlighted.

And the reason I found for that is in `point.highlight(e);` in `componendDidMount`

For second series, this line giving error on hover:
[image]

More specifically, `point.highligh(e)` is calling top function: `H.Point.prototype.highlight = ()`, check top of the question, in that function this function call is resulting in error

```
this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this);
```

Note: I'll try to reproduce and create a jsfiddle or something like that, but posting this just so if anyone can help figure this out.

And I am passing Array of Object in Series data, because I need more informative tooltip on chart point:

```
data: [{
    "x": "2018-12-23T11:00:09.311Z",
    "y": 107.54,
    "data": {
       "Toltip Info 1": "1,884,681,725",
       "Tooltip info 2": "158,039,757.99",
       "price":"107.54"
    }
}]
```

Here is demo of the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/pk2w85jpk0

Comment: Hi Rahul Sagore, I tried to reproduce your problem, but synchronized charts - one with two line series, one with one column series works fine after small modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h18vnqcg/ Please check the example and let me know if it helped.

Comment: I found that you have commented the `refresh` function, but still the same issue. And to update, I have this type of data: Array of object 
`[{"x":"2018-12-23T11:00:09.311Z","y":107.54,"data":{"Toltip Info 1":"1,884,681,725","Tooltip info 2":"158,039,757.99","price":"107.54"}}]`

Comment: Hi Rahul Sagore, Yes `refresh` method it is unnecessary in this case. Please reproduce your porblem in jsfiddle, because in my example everything seems to work.

Comment: @ppotaczek  you can check the demo I've created, let me know if something is wrong with the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pk2w85jpk0

Comment: It looks like the problem is caused by your `x` data format. If you change the format to milliseconds, everything works: https://codesandbox.io/s/ovk25m493q

Comment: @ppotaczek Oh thanks. I knew it that it has to be related to data format, that is why mentioned in above comment. You can post that as an answer, I'll mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the data format, `x` values should be in milliseconds:

```
        data: [
          {
            x: new Date("2018-12-25T09:00:06.247Z").getTime(),
            y: 6609592859.48
          },
          ...
        ]
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/ovk25m493q